# generating random number with a specific distribution in c

Tags: c

i need a library with functions for generating random number, given average, standard deviation and using one of three distribution - exponential, normal or unified.

even one of the three would help.
i'm looking for something like this - http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/zigurat.aspx, but in c.

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**uniform:**

Generate a random number in the range [0,1] with [uniform distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1340729/how-do-you-generate-a-random-double-uniformly-distributed-between-0-and-1-from-c):

```
double X=((double)rand()/(double)RAND_MAX);
```

**Exponentional**

 generating an [exponentional random variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6527345/simulating-poisson-waiting-times-java/6527433#6527433) with parameter lambda:

```
-ln(U)/lambda (where U~Uniform[0,1]).
```

**normal:** 

the simplest way [though time consuming] is using the [central limit theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem), [sum enough uniformly distributed numbers] but there are other methods in the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution) such as the [box muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform) that generates 2 independent random variables: X,Y~N(0,1)

```
X=sqrt(-2ln(U))*cos(2*pi*V)
Y=sqrt(-2ln(U))*sin(2*pi*V)
where U,V~UNIFORM[0,1]
```

transforming from X~N(0,1) to Z~N(m,s^2) is simple: `Z = s*X + m`

Though you CAN generate these random numbers, I stand by @Amigable Clark Kant suggestion to use an existing library.

Comment: If the platform supports C++11, then the new, powerful random number facility is available. It already supports 20 common distributions. See the [C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#std-random).

Answer (score 15):

May I recommend the [GNU Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl) either for use or for inspiration? It has several [Random Number Distributions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distributions.html) and is designed to be used from C and C++.