# Is random.expovariate equivalent to a Poisson Process

Tags: python, math, statistics, poisson

I read somewhere that the python library function random.expovariate produces intervals equivalent to Poisson Process events.
Is that really the case or should I impose some other function on the results?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On a strict reading of your question, yes, that is what random.expovariate does.

expovariate gives you random floating point numbers, exponentially distributed.  In a Poisson process the size of the interval between consecutive events is exponential.

However, there are two other ways I could imagine modelling poisson processes

1. Just generate random numbers, uniformly distributed and sort them.
2. Generate integers which have a Poisson distribution (i.e. they are distributed like the number of events within a fixed interval in a Poisson process).  Use numpy.random.poisson to do this.

Of course all three things are quite different.  The right choice depends on your application.

Comment: About 1., @AdrianRatnapala, does a sequence of uniformly distributed random numbers on [0, 100], *sorted*,  model a Poisson process? Why?

Comment: @Basj The need to sort also depends on the application.  The Poission process is a _set_ (i.e. unordered) of uniformly distributed events.  A list or array of generated data would also contain "unwanted" information about what order they were generated in.  Sorting destroys that information.

Answer (score 5):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10250877/1587329 gives a nice explanation of why this works (not only in python), and some code. In short

> simulate the first 10 events in a poisson process with an averate rate
>   of 15 arrivals per second like this:
>
> ```
> import random
> for i in range(1,10):
>    print random.expovariate(15)
> ```