# Poisson Process and multiprocessing. Is there a better solution?

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing, poisson

I've to simulate load on a web application.

I wrote a python code that generate random requests following an exponential distribution.

The request is a simple url-get: i measure the response time and i store it on a file.

So, for a given time the code create a new process that perform the request, then he sleeps for a random time given by random.expovariate(lambd).

When i start a request i also store a timestamp to check if the average is close to 1/lambda.

I've problem when i set lambda > 20: the average is more high than 1/lambda and this results in a slow execution.

I test the random generator and it is very good, so i think the problem is when the system has to create a new process.

Is there a way to speed up this phase?

Perhaps there are some limits on processes creation?

I forgot to say that the python version is 2.7.3 and i can't upgrade it.

Using pypy there are some performance improvements but problem persist.

Here the code:

```
def request(results,url):
    start = time.time()
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
    except:
        noactions
    else:
        # Append results (in seconds)
        results.write("{0},{1}\n".format(start,r.elapsed.microseconds/1e6))

def main():
    # Open results file
    results = open(responseTimes.txt",'a')
    processes = []
    # Perform requests for time t (seconds) with rate lambda=l
    start = time.time()
    elapsed = 0
    while (t > elapsed):
        p = Process(target=request, args=(results,url,))
        p.daemon = True
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
        time.sleep(random.expovariate(l))
        elapsed = time.time() - start   
    # Wait for all processes to finish
    [p.join() for p in processes]
    # Close the file
    results.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis**

It is likely that you are creating too many processes and that slows the system down. While creating a process usually takes less than 1.0/20 seconds, when there are too many this may well increase above 1.0/20, resulting in the observed rate:

```
from timeit import timeit
from multiprocessing import Process

def launch():
   Process().start()

for n in [1, 10, 100]:
   print timeit(stmt=launch, number=n)

# time in seconds to launch a process
# as measured on a 2.7 GHz Core i7 Mac Mini with OSX 10.9
0.000946998596191
0.00857591629028
0.0778558254242
```

These numbers may vary on your machine depending on factors like work load, CPU, memory etc.

**Solution**

Thas said, you should rather use an approach whereby you start say 10-20 processes (or even better: threads, as they take less overhead), each of which issues requests at a rate of 1/lambda:

```
def worker(n, results, url, l):
    print "worker %d started" % n
    while(True):
        # request the first URL
        request(results, url)
        # wait for next event with poission-process time lag
        time.sleep(random.expovariate(l))

def main():
    # your code to initialise
    ...
    # set parameters
    t = 100
    l = 20
    # start n workers
    n = 10
    processes=[]
    for i in range(0,n):
        print "starting worker %d" % i
        p = Process(target=worker, args=(i,results,url,l,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    # now wait for requested time
    time.sleep(t)
    # stop workers
    for p in processes:
        p.terminate()
```

Comment: I need to simulate a Poisson process and this is not a good solution. I resolved the problem using [httperf](http://www.hpl.hp.com/research/linux/httperf/)

Comment: of course you can use httperf, it basically does the same thing is my code example. The expovariate function essentially creates events of a poisson process. (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8592048/is-random-expovariate-equivalent-to-a-poisson-process).